# loop multiple select statements - oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Is it possible that I can use loop on this script ?  I used same sql statement  but the only difference is the value of the field (NAME).

Can u help/assist me

```
    select 

distinct 

(select  VALUE 
from TABLE1 
where O_ID = a.O_ID 
and NAME ='Activity')Activity  ,

(select  VALUE 
from TABLE1 
where O_ID = a.O_ID 
and NAME ='code') code ,

(select  VALUE 
from TABLE1 
where O_ID = a.O_ID 
and NAME ='object')object,

from TABLE1 a
where a.O_ID   = 15850196

;
```

Comment: what do you mean by loop?why do you want to use it?

Comment: you probably could create a function... and then use it in your `select`

Comment: @ksl123- Loop .. came to my mind may be possible solution and to catch also the rows that are not listed on my script.

Comment: @Plirkee.. thanks.. but i only have a read only access ... so is there other way ?

Comment: If understood you correctly - you have no permission to create functions. In that case the only thing I can think of is the usage of `with` clause which is not exactly what you want - but can make your query more readable.

Comment: @Plirkee..as long as it works like a loop and catches all the rows .. It's good for me.. can u teach me how ? I'am not yet familiar with     with statement ...  Thanks :)

Comment: Proper formatting is the key to SQL!

Comment: @jarlh - I only have a read only access .. What will you suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that in your case you will gain enough by using `with` clause ... but since you cannot create functions you could re-write your queries as follows:

```
with 
Activities as (select O_ID , VALUE from TABLE1 where NAME ='Activity'), 
codes  as     (select O_ID , VALUE from TABLE1 where NAME ='code') ,
objects as    (select O_ID , VALUE from TABLE1 where NAME ='object') 
select 
(select VALUE from Activities where a.O_ID = O_ID) as Activity, 
(select VALUE from codes where a.O_ID = O_ID) as code, 
(select VALUE from objects where a.O_ID = O_ID) as object   
from TABLE1 a
where a.O_ID   = 15850196
```

or

```
with 
Activities as (select O_ID , VALUE from TABLE1 where NAME ='Activity'), 
codes  as     (select O_ID , VALUE from TABLE1 where NAME ='code') ,
objects as    (select O_ID , VALUE from TABLE1 where NAME ='object') 
select 
Activity.value, codes.value, objects.value 
from TABLE1 a,Activities, codes, objects    
where a.O_ID   = 15850196 and
      a.O_ID =  Activities.O_ID(+) and 
      a.O_ID =  codes.O_ID(+)  and 
      a.O_ID =  objects.O_ID(+)
```

Comment: May I ask what will happen on below codes?

    with 
    Activities as (select O_ID , VALUE from TABLE1 where NAME ='Activity'), 
    codes  as     (select O_ID , VALUE from TABLE1 where NAME ='code') ,
    objects as    (select O_ID , VALUE from TABLE1 where NAME ='object') 

In my example i used 3 items .. activity/code/object .. now my question is .. in this query , can i catch fields that are not listed on the table1?  

sample..there NAME ='Timing'  ....

Comment: @ReynanSantiago Well I guess for timing you would need to add a new sub query `timings as     (select O_ID , VALUE from TABLE1 where NAME ='Timing') ... I am not quite sure what are you trying to achieve - but your having only r/o is quite restricting ...

Comment: Thanks Man !  for the effort.. appreciate it ! 

Maybe I' am looking for a script .. like ...counting each rows and will stop if he gets to the end ..

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be one of those annoying key/value tables. You want activity, code and object for ID 15850196, but as there is not simply a table containing these columns, you must look up each value in the key/value table instead.

One common solution for this is conditional aggregation:

```
select
  max(case when name ='Activity' then value end) as activity,
  max(case when name ='code' then value end) as code,
  max(case when name ='object' then value end) as object
from table1
where o_id = 15850196;
```

Comment: what will 'MAX' do ?

Comment: You want one result row with the values for o_id = 15850196. So you need aggregation. You could as well use `MIN` instead of `MAX`, because there should only be one entry per name and o_id anyway. MySQL has a function called `ANY_VALUE` for this, which makes it more clear, that we don't actually look for a minimum or maximum, but Oracle doesn't have this function, so we use `MIN` or `MAX`.

Comment: Thanks ! It helps ! meaning no more 'Distinct' code ?

just also want to add ... if there's a way that we can work it like a loop.. co'z if i have 10,000 values on NAME .. it's tedious and hard to code ..

Comment: 10000 different attributes? And you store all these in a key/value table? And what do you want your result to look like? One row with 10000 columns?

Comment: Yes..diiff value on Name that will result on 10000 columns

Comment: Funny. Well, I don't find typing this SQL so tedious. I'd select all distinct names and then use Excel or a text editor to construct the lines for the query. This should take no longer than some five minutes.

Comment: Yes, It's possible .. same thing that I used , but my worry is .. if someone insert new record ..  ..it will be missed.. since we are using hard code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165564/discussion-between-thorsten-kettner-and-reynan-santiago).